# Check for username and password in a text file

Tags: java, swing

I have to implement a login system and for this purpose when an account is created i save the data in a text file. the data is in the format {username} {password} {bestScore}. But when it comes to the login and i have more users. My algorithm checks every single line of the text file and if the user exists go to the main menu panel. If the username is wrong open joptionpane telling the user that username is incorrect or same for the password. The thing is that it executes for the first line of the file in all the cases and the while loop breaks. Thats not my idea. I want to check for the username and password match in the entire text file. Not for every line of the file. This is my code (which is not working the way i want) :

```
private static final Pattern usernameAndPasswordPattern = Pattern.compile("^(\\S+) (\\S+) ([0-9]+)$");
loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Niki\\Desktop\\Java Projects\\QuizGame\\QuizGame\\usernames.txt"))))) {
                String line = br.readLine();

                while (line != null) {
                    Matcher userNameAndPasswordMatcher = usernameAndPasswordPattern.matcher(line);

                    if (userNameAndPasswordMatcher.matches()) {
                        String username = userNameAndPasswordMatcher.group(1);
                        String password = userNameAndPasswordMatcher.group(2);
                        String bestScore = userNameAndPasswordMatcher.group(3);

                        String pwd = new String(passField.getPassword());

                        if (username.equals(usernameField.getText()) && !password.equals(pwd)) {
                            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Incorrect password!", "Login incomplete", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                            if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                                passField.setText("");
                            }                           
                        }
                        else if (!username.equals(usernameField.getText()) && password.equals(pwd)) {
                            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Incorrect username!", "Login incomplete", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                            if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                                usernameField.setText("");
                            }
                        }
                        else if (!username.equals(usernameField.getText()) && !password.equals(pwd)) {
                            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "This account don't exist!", "Login incomplete", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                            if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                                usernameField.setText("");
                                passField.setText("");
                            }
                        }
                        else if (username.equals(usernameField.getText()) && password.equals(pwd)) {
                            gd.setCurrentUser(username);
                            gd.setBestScore(Integer.parseInt(bestScore));

                            rdialog = new RedirectingDialog(frame);
                            rdialog.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    }
                    line = br.readLine();
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    });
```

Here you can see that in the first line of input i will go to the one of the 4 cases and the while loop will stop. But if the username is on the second line for example i got the Dialog with message "Incorrect username". One of my ideas is to append everything from the file to a `StringBuilder` and then with `.contains` to check if username and password exist but i feel it kinda wrong because if i match username and password with contains it will check in the entire text file for combinations. E.g username can be on the first line password can be on the 3rd line and there will be match. Thats not what i want. They have to be on the same line to have the match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I think you need to get your requirements precise — then it will be much easier to think about what is right and wrong in the program.

I assume that is the user name is correct, then it will appear exactly once in the file. If the user name is incorrect, it will most likely not appear in the file; however, we cannot rule out the possibility that someone accidentally enters someone else’s user name if the names are somewhat like each other.

In the two cases where `!username.equals(usernameField.getText())` you shouldn’t do anything, just continue searching through the file for the correct user name.

Once you find the correct username, you can do what you have to do depending on whether the password is correct or not. After that, if you like you can break out of the loop because you know that you will not find the user name again later in the file.

Finally, if you’ve gone all the way through the file without finding the user name, you should issue the message about the user name being incorrect.

In code, something like this (not tested):

```
            boolean userNameFound = false;
            while (line != null) {
                Matcher userNameAndPasswordMatcher = usernameAndPasswordPattern.matcher(line);

                if (userNameAndPasswordMatcher.matches()) {
                    String username = userNameAndPasswordMatcher.group(1);
                    String password = userNameAndPasswordMatcher.group(2);
                    String bestScore = userNameAndPasswordMatcher.group(3);

                    String pwd = new String(passField.getPassword());

                    if (username.equals(usernameField.getText())) {
                        userNameFound = true;
                        if (password.equals(pwd)) {
                            gd.setCurrentUser(username);
                            gd.setBestScore(Integer.parseInt(bestScore));

                            rdialog = new RedirectingDialog(frame);
                            rdialog.setVisible(true);
                        } else { // password does not match
                            int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Incorrect password!", "Login incomplete", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                            if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                                passField.setText("");
                            }                           
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (! userNameFound) {
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Incorrect password!", "Login incomplete", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
                    passField.setText("");
                }                           
            }
```

Comment: Dude this perfectly works. You just missed the `line = br.read()` in the while loop everything worked as i want. Thanks!